# Django authentication stops working when I add a logout function

Tags: django, authentication

I made this simple Django site which justs logs a user in:

```
def main(request):
    # User is already logged in and redirected to main
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'mysite/main.html')

    # User is attempting to log in
    elif 'username' in request.POST:
        return login(request)

    # Return login page
    return render(request, 'mysite/login.html')

def login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    logged_in = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if logged_in is not None:
        return render(request, 'mysite/main.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'mysite/login.html')
```

All of this worked without any problems. I could refresh the page and I was still logged in, and '{{ request.user.username }}' in main.html worked as intended. Then I added a way to log out. It's just a link in main.html, pointing to logout/, which points to this view:

```
def log_out(request):
    print "logging out"
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

After I had logged out for the first time, the authentication stopped working properly. I can still log in if I enter the correct username and password, but '{{ request.user.username }}' doesn't output anything anymore, and if I refresh the page while at main.html I now end up at login.html.

Why is this happening? Why is the authentication ruined by me logging out once?

Comment: A suggestion, before logging out the request, you verify that the user associated with the request is authenticated or not. You user, `request.user.is_authenticated()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of logout is not to blame here. You are missing an important step in the login process: you don't call `auth.login()`.

`authenticate()` only returns an authenticated user; you still need to log that user in.